# Ruby - Get all files in a directory from shallower to deeper

Tags: ruby

By the magic of `Dir` I can get all files in a directory:

```
Dir['lib/**/*.rb']
=> ["lib/a.rb", "lib/foo/bar/c.rb", "lib/foo/b.rb"]
```

But I want to iterate them from shallower to deeper. i.e. `a.rb` -> `b.rb` -> `c.rb`.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could sort them by the amount of slashes, which may not be very efficient but easy:

```
["lib/a.rb", "lib/foo/bar/c.rb", "lib/foo/b.rb"].sort_by { |s| s.count('/') }
#=> ["lib/a.rb", "lib/foo/b.rb", "lib/foo/bar/c.rb"]
```

Or use `group_by` and get an array of files per directory level:

```
["lib/a.rb", "lib/foo/bar/c.rb", "lib/foo/b.rb"].group_by { |s| s.count('/') }
#=> {1=>["lib/a.rb"], 3=>["lib/foo/bar/c.rb"], 2=>["lib/foo/b.rb"]}
```